# Scala Combinators JavaTokennParsers '||' expected but '>' found

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

When I run this test:

```
import com.dvMENTALmadness.parsers.{BinaryOp, ExprType, Number, SimpleEquationParser}
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class SimpleEquationParserTest extends FlatSpec {
  "(1+2) > (3+4)" should " == false" in {
    val result = SimpleEquationParser("(1+2) > (3+4)")
    println(result)
    assert( result == Right(BinaryOp(">",BinaryOp("+",Number(1.0),Number(2.0),ExprType.Num),BinaryOp("+",Number(3.0),Number(4.0),ExprType.Num),ExprType.Bool)) )
  }
}
```

I get:

```
Left("`||' expected but `>' found") did not equal Right(BinaryOp(>,BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num),BinaryOp(+,Number(3.0),Number(4.0),Num),Bool))
```

If I change the expression to `((1+2) > (3+4))` it works but I need to be able to support the optional parentheses. Any suggestions? Below are the class definition as well as the log trace:

```
package com.dvMENTALmadness.parsers

import com.dvMENTALmadness.parsers.ExprType.ExprType
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.{JavaTokenParsers, PackratParsers}

sealed trait Expr
sealed trait Var extends Expr {
  def key: String
}
object ExprType extends Enumeration {
  type ExprType = Value
  val Var, Num, Text, Bool = Value
}

case class Text(value: String) extends Expr
case class Number(value: Double) extends Expr
case class Bool(value: Boolean) extends Expr
case class NumericVar(key: String) extends Var
case class TextVar(key: String) extends Var
case class BoolVar(key: String) extends Var
case class AnyVar(key: String) extends Var
case class UnaryOp(operator: String, arg: Expr, expType: ExprType) extends Expr
case class BinaryOp(operator: String, left : Expr, right: Expr, expType: ExprType)  extends Expr

trait ExprParser extends JavaTokenParsers with PackratParsers {

  def foldExpr(etype: ExprType)(pat: Expr ~ List[String ~ Expr]) : Expr = pat match {
    case left ~ xs => xs.foldLeft(left)((left, acc) => acc match {
      case op ~ right => BinaryOp(op, left, right, etype)
    })
  }

  // see: http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-scala-parser-combinators.html
  implicit def toLogged(name: String) = new {
    def !!![T](p:Parser[T]) = log(p)(name) // for debugging
    //def !!![T](p:Parser[T]) = p         // for production
  }
}

trait BoolParser extends ExprParser {

  // Operator precedence: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_operators.htm
  def expr = "expr" !!! bool_expr | num_expr | text_expr
  def bool_expr = "bool_expr" !!! or | bool_term
  def num_expr = "num_expr" !!! num_equality | num_term
  def text_expr = "text_expr" !!! text_equality

  // operations
  def or = "or" !!! and ~ rep("||" ~ and) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Bool)
  def and = "and" !!! equality ~ rep("&&" ~ equality) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Bool)

  def equality = "equality" !!! bool_equality | num_equality | text_equality
  def bool_equality = "bool_equality" !!! bool_term ~ rep("==" ~ bool_term | "!=" ~ bool_term) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Bool)
  def num_equality = "num_equality" !!! relational ~ rep("==" ~ relational | "!=" ~ relational) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Num)
  def text_equality = "text_equality" !!! concat ~ rep("==" ~ concat | "!=" ~ concat) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Text)

  def relational = "relational" !!! additive ~ rep(">=" ~ additive | "<=" ~ additive | ">" ~ additive | "<" ~ additive) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Num)
  def additive = "additive" !!! multiplicative ~ rep("+" ~ multiplicative | "-" ~ multiplicative) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Num)
  def multiplicative = "multiplicative" !!! num_term ~ rep("*" ~ num_term | "/" ~ num_term | "%" ~ num_term) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Num)
  def concat = "concat" !!! text ~ rep("+" ~ text) ^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Text)

  def operators = "*" | "/" | "%" | "+" | "-" | "&&" | "||"

  // terms
  def term = "term" !!! bool_term | num_term
  def bool_term = "bool_term" !!! bool | bool_parens | not
  def num_term = "num_term" !!!  num | num_parens | neg

  def not:PackratParser[Expr] = "not" !!! "!" ~> bool_term ^^ (x => UnaryOp("!", x, ExprType.Bool))
  def neg:PackratParser[Expr] = "neg" !!! "-" ~> num_term ^^ (x => UnaryOp("-", x, ExprType.Num))

  def parens:PackratParser[Expr] = "parens" !!! "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
  def bool_parens:PackratParser[Expr] = "bool_parens" !!! "(" ~> bool_expr <~ ")"
  def num_parens:PackratParser[Expr] = "num_parens" !!! "(" ~> num_expr <~ ")"
  def text_parens:PackratParser[Expr] = "text_parens" !!! "(" ~> text_expr <~ ")"

  //values
  def bool: PackratParser[Expr] = "bool" !!!
    "true" ^^^ (Bool(true)) |
    "false" ^^^ (Bool(false)) |
    var_factor

  def num: PackratParser[Expr] = "num" !!!
    floatingPointNumber ^^ (x => Number(x.toDouble)) |
    wholeNumber ^^ (x => Number(x.toDouble)) |
    var_factor

  def text: PackratParser[Expr] = "text" !!!
    stringLiteral ^^ (x => Text(stripQuote(x))) |
    var_factor

  def var_factor: Parser[Expr] = "var_factor" !!!
    id <~ ".asNumber" ^^ (x => NumericVar(x)) |
    id <~ ".asText" ^^ (x => TextVar(x)) |
    id <~ ".asBool" ^^ (x => BoolVar(x)) |
    id ^^ (x => AnyVar(x))

  def id: PackratParser[String] = "id" !!! opt("{") ~> ident <~ opt("}")

  private def stripQuote(s: String) = {
    s.substring(1, s.length - 1)
  }
}

object SimpleEquationParser  extends BoolParser {
  def apply(input: String) : Either[String,Expr] = {

    parseAll("root" !!! expr, input) match {
      case Success(r, _) => Right(r)
      case Failure(msg, _) => Left(msg)
      case Error(msg, _) => Left(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

The log trace:

```
trying root at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying expr at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying bool_expr at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying or at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying and at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying equality at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying bool_equality at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying bool_term at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying bool at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
bool --> [1.1] failure: `true' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
trying var_factor at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
id --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
var_factor --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
id --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
id --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
id --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
bool_term --> [1.1] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `(' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
^
trying bool_parens at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader@30b7c004
trying bool_expr at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying or at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying and at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying equality at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying bool_equality at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying bool_term at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying bool at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
bool --> [1.2] failure: `true' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying var_factor at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
id --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
var_factor --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
id --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
id --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying id at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
id --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
bool_term --> [1.2] failure: string matching regex `\p{javaJavaIdentifierStart}\p{javaJavaIdentifierPart}*' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying bool_parens at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
bool_parens --> [1.2] failure: `(' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying not at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
not --> [1.2] failure: `!' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
bool_equality --> [1.2] failure: `!' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
equality --> [1.2] failure: `!' expected but `1' found

(1+2) > (3+4)
 ^
trying num_equality at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying relational at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying additive at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying multiplicative at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying num_term at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
trying num at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@59d016c9
num --> [1.3] parsed: 1
num_term --> [1.3] parsed: Number(1.0)
multiplicative --> [1.3] parsed: (Number(1.0)~List())
trying multiplicative at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@36c88a32
trying num_term at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@36c88a32
trying num at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$PackratReader$$anon$3@36c88a32
num --> [1.5] parsed: 2
num_term --> [1.5] parsed: Number(2.0)
multiplicative --> [1.5] parsed: (Number(2.0)~List())
additive --> [1.5] parsed: (Number(1.0)~List((+~Number(2.0))))
relational --> [1.5] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
num_equality --> [1.5] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
and --> [1.5] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
or --> [1.5] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
bool_expr --> [1.5] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
bool_parens --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
bool_equality --> [1.6] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
equality --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
and --> [1.6] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
or --> [1.6] parsed: (BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)~List())
bool_expr --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
expr --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
root --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)
Left(`||' expected but `>' found)
```

Comment: Note that `(1+2)` is parsed with `bool_expr`: `bool_parens --> [1.6] parsed: BinaryOp(+,Number(1.0),Number(2.0),Num)`. But it should be parsed with a `num_expr` for the required `relational` parser to be considered.

Comment: Also, I believe that some types in `foldExpr` are wrong. E.g. in `num_equality` the result should be `ExprType.Bool`, but it has `^^ foldExpr(ExprType.Num)`.

Comment: @Kolmar I was able to get it working by swapping the order of equality parsers so that `num_equality` comes before `bool_equality`. However when I did that `true` and `false` were parsed as `ident` values instead of reserved boolean keywords. So I've added a `reserved` parser to correct for that. I believe that falls in line with your recommendation.

Comment: @Kolmar as for `foldExpr`, I'm using those types simplify my evaluator logic. It informs the evaluator not about the output, but the inputs. It's possibly a design flaw. I'm open to recommendations but I'd hate to get this thread on a tangent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kolmar is correct that the input needs to be parsed with `num_expr`. The solution below is what I came up with, but it feels less robust than I would like. The issue boils down to precedence but I was hoping that there was a way to get the parser to continue checking after the boolean branch fails. Instead I swapped the order of the `equality` parser to check `num_equality` before `bool_equality`:

```
def equality = "equality" !!! num_equality | bool_equality | text_equality
```

But because `true` and `false` keywords are defined in the boolean branch, which is evaluated after numeric values, they were parsed as type `AnyVar` instead of `Bool`. To fix that I added a `reserved` parser and changed the `var_factor` to the following:

```
def var_factor: Parser[Expr] = "var_factor" !!!
  id <~ ".asNumber" ^^ (x => NumericVar(x)) |
  id <~ ".asText" ^^ (x => TextVar(x)) |
  id <~ ".asBool" ^^ (x => BoolVar(x)) |
  not(reserved) ~> id ^^ (x => AnyVar(x))

def id: PackratParser[String] = "id" !!! opt("{") ~> ident <~ opt("}")
def reserved: Parser[String] = """\b(true|false)\b""".r
```

I currently have about 70 tests that are all now passing. I'm still open to suggestions for more robust solutions (less brittle) but this seems to be working well enough for now.